# Use included XML files in deployed server

Tags: python, docker, server, web-deployment, google-cloud-run

I have xml files that reside in the directory like this

```
src
 |---lib
 |    |---folder
 |    |    |---XML files
 |    |---script.py
 |---app.py
```

The app.py file runs the codes in script.py, and in script.py it requires the XML files. When I run the server locally (window) I can just use the relative path "lib\folder\'xml files'". But when I deploy my server to Cloud Run, it says the files don't exist.

I've tried to specify the absolute path by doing this in script.py

```
package_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
path = os.path.join(package_directory, "folder\'xml files")
```

and tried changing all backward dash to forward dash, but the error still occurs.

In the dockerfile, I had this:

```
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./
```

which I believe to copy everything in the src folder except things specified in .dockerignore, which I had these insides:

```
Dockerfile
README.md
*.pyc
*.pyo
*.pyd
__pycache__
.pytest_cache
```

Comment: Have you tried /app/src/lib/folder/xml files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Cloud Run requires a container, a good test for you would be to create the container and run it locally. I suspect that it's your container that's incorrect rather than Cloud Run.

I created the following repro of your code:

```sh
.
├── app.py
├── Dockerfile
└── lib
    ├── folder
    │   └── XML files
    │       └── test
    ├── __init__.py
    └── script.py
```

`app.py`:

```py
from lib import script

script.foo()
```

`script.py`:

```py
import os

def foo():
    package_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    path = os.path.join(package_directory, "folder/XML files")

    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path,f)):
            print(f)
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM docker.io/python:3.9.9

ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR ${APP_HOME}

COPY . ./

ENTRYPOINT ["python","app.py"]
```

And, when I build|run the container, it correctly reports `test`:

```sh
Q="70734734"

podman build \
--tag=${Q} \
--file=./Dockerfile \
.

podman run \
--interactive --tty \
localhost/${Q}
```

I'm confident that, if I were to push it to Cloud Run, it would work correctly there too.

> **NOTE**
>
> 1. Try to avoid spaces in directory names; `os.path.join` accommodates spaces
> 2. You describe `XML files` but your code references `xml files`
> 3. You don't include a full repro of your issue making it more difficult to help you

Comment: Ahh you are right. I was fixing another issue with CORS and found out an illegal import of a library causes both of these errors. I'd have definitely upvoted if I had more reputation! Thank you!